# google.script.run invoke whole server script instead a function? WHY?

Tags: json, google-apps-script

```
var saved = new Date();
setTimeout(() => console.log(saved, new Date()), 1000);
setTimeout(() => console.log(saved, new Date()), 2000);
```

Execute this primitive script on any javascript engine, you will see output like this (look at seconds):

```
2018-02-21T22:50:29.066Z 2018-02-21T22:50:30.071Z
2018-02-21T22:50:29.066Z 2018-02-21T22:50:31.070Z
```

All dates in first column are equal (because it is the only SAVED date).

But if you execute similar script in Google apps script:

```
///// code.gs /////

function doGet() { // a main window maker
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}

var saved = new Date(); // <<< our hero

function getDates() {
  return JSON.stringify({saved: saved, now: new Date()});


///// index.html /////

look at your browser console
<script>
setTimeout(() => google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(console.log)
  .getDates()
  , 1000);
setTimeout(() => google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(console.log)
  .getDates()
  , 2000);
</script>
```

You will see output like this (look at seconds):

```
{"saved":"2018-02-21T23:03:58.663Z","now":"2018-02-21T23:03:58.664Z"}
{"saved":"2018-02-21T23:03:59.655Z","now":"2018-02-21T23:03:59.656Z"}
```

Every time you call the server script from a client side by google.script.run the variable `saved` is updating!!!

What a hell??? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing persists between runs in Google Script. In that sense, this is an expected outcome. It has to set a new `saved` value, because otherwise inside of the function `getDates()` the variable `saved` wouldn't even be declared. If you wish to actualy **store** a value to use for multiple runs, you will need to use the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) or set an actual set value with `.setHours()` and so on.

Comment: There with Date() was a synthetic example. In my real script I declare a class and then an instance of the class: `var instance = new MyClass(42)` and every time I call any method of my class: `instance.method()` every time I encounter the fact that the class is being redeclared and the instance is reinitialized. This is really expected behavior??? I cannot save all my instances in the properties or cache service. Why then the server part of the script is? For a what?

Comment: Doesn't matter whether it is synthetic or not. To my understanding, once the script is done running, the environment is cleared and released so it can be used for someone else's script (someone can correct me if I am wrong). In essence, once you finish running a script, all variable values are gone. As to why there are many reasons we can speculate on that are probably right (like utilizing resources and not keeping them wasted for one script that may not run again for several hours) but best be asked from Google

Comment: Hmmm... I thought the “server environment” exists as long as the page is open in the browser. Thank you for your answers, Vytautas!